# Compare headers of dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to compare the headers of two pandas dataframes and filter the columns that match.
df1 is my big dataframe with two headers, df2 is sort of a dictionary where I have saved every column header I will need from df1.

So if df1 is something like this:

```
    A         B         C         D
    a         b         c         d
 0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
 1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
-0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
 0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
-0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
-0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
```

and df2 is something like this:

```
   B         D         E
```

I need to get the output:

```
     B          D
 -0.282863  -1.135632
 -0.173215  -1.044236
 -2.104569   1.071804
 -0.706771   0.271860
  0.567020  -1.087401
  0.113648   0.524988
```

and also a list of the header elements that were not matching:

```
A      C
```

as well as elements missing from df1:

```
E
```

So far I have tried the iloc command and a lot of different suggestions here on stackoverflow for comparing rows. Since I am comparing the headers though it was not possible.

EDIT: I have tried

```
df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
```

but the result is:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[], []],
           labels=[[], []])
```

Is this because of the multiple headers?

Comment: Please provide the code that you've written that comes closest to what you want to do.

Comment: please provide: df1.head().to_dict(). Looks strange in my eyes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's are couple of methods, for given `df1` and `df2`

```
In [1041]: df1.columns
Out[1041]: Index([u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'], dtype='object')

In [1042]: df2.columns
Out[1042]: Index([u'B', u'D', u'E'], dtype='object')
```

Columns in both `df1` and `df2`

```
In [1046]: df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
Out[1046]: Index([u'B', u'D'], dtype='object')
```

Columns in `df1` not in `df2`

```
In [1047]: df1.columns.difference(df2.columns)
Out[1047]: Index([u'A', u'C'], dtype='object')
```

Columns in `df2` not in `df1`

```
In [1048]: df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)
Out[1048]: Index([u'E'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: The intersection does not work, I get an empty result, see my edit above. Is this because of the multiple headers?

Comment: The header was wrong, now I fixed it and your solution works. Thank you!